# How do I remove the '\0' character that appears in a file after using fread?

Tags: php, video, fread

I have a video file which I need to grab using a function instead of a direct link.
When I view the video page code of the direct link, this is what I have on screen:

[image]

But when I use my function, first of all the video wont run, and when I view the code, this appears:

[image]

I realized it's the same file, the same characters, but with many \0 characters in the middle. These are the one's in yellow.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$file_name = --path to file--;
$file_size = filesize($file_name);
$ctype = 'video/mp4';

header('Content-Type: '.$ctype);
header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");    
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$file = fopen($file_name, 'rb');
$read = fread($file, $file_size);
print($read);
fclose($file);
exit;
```

Do I need to change the code? Is there something to make fread read the file properly?
Or do I need to do some kind of processing to the file to be displayed?

Comment: The NUL bytes are there in the original file, but your browser does not display them because they are NUL bytes and there is nothing to render them as. They are supposed to be there. Why do you think you need to remove them?

Comment: Also note that since your code is making no effort to handle byte ranges, you should remove the `header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");` line

Comment: Because the video isn't displayed so there must be something wrong with the data.

Comment: Use cURL instead of classic PHP functions, it solves all the problems

Comment: @Martin How does curl in any way apply to the above code sample?

Comment: @Sarah Try using `readfile()` instead of `fopen()`/`fread()`/`fclose()` - having said that there's no real reason why your code shouldn't work (assuming that the file path is correct) - you should (for once) ensure that `display_errors` is off in case a PHP error is corrupting the file. If you are having a problem viewing it, use VLC to open it and show the messages that appear in it's error console here.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you! It finally worked!

Comment: @DaveRandom Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) instead of `fopen()`/`fread()`/`fclose()`. It will be more memory efficient and less susceptible to errors.

Having said that there's no real reason why your code shouldn't work (assuming that the file path is correct) - you should (for once) ensure that `display_errors` is off in case a PHP error is corrupting the file. You can do this by setting `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` at the top of your script.

Comment: @Sarah It's also worth mentioning the existence of `fpassthru()` if you are dealing with/prefer to deal with file pointers.

Comment: @Sarah Also, for future reference, another common gotcha with what you are doing is leading/trailing whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags (of which there should be none)

Comment: There's something else. I already processed the video file to be streamed while playing. Before, the whole file needed to be downloaded before it started playing, but now it's fine, using the direct link, it streams while playing, and I can move the location back and forth while streaming just like the youtube video.

When I use my function, it also streams while playing, but I can't move the location of the pointer. When I move it, it goes back to the location where it stopped playing. Why does this happen?

Comment: @Sarah It's likely related to the headers you are sending. Adding a `Content-Disposition: inline` header may help. Also ensure that output buffering is disabled.